# estructuras repetitivas en pseint

Tags: bucles, pseint, estructuras, pseudocódigo, repetidos

Diseñe un algoritmo (diagrama de flujo y pseudocódigo) que
calcule el cuadrado de un número entero N mediante la suma
de los N primeros impares. Por ejemplo, el cuadrado de 5
puede calcularse como la suma de los 5 primeros impares
1+3+5+7+9 cuyo resultado es 25. Tenga en cuenta que el
cálculo puede realizarse tanto para valores positivos como
negativos. Desarrolle una versión para cada estructura
repetitiva estudiada y realice la prueba de escritorio
correspondiente para N=4, N=5 y N6 (un valor para cada
estructura).
ya hice un algoritmo para la estructura para pero no se como seguir con mientras y repetir
hasta ahora así va mi algoritmo:

```
Proceso cuadrado_mientraspunto6
        Definir num, i,cuadrado,impares como real;
        Escribir "ingrese numeros";
        Leer num;
        impares<-1;
        cuadrado<-0;
        Mientras expresion logica Hacer
            cuadrado<-cuadrado+impares;
            impares<-impares+2;
        Fin Mientras
        Escribir "el valor del cuadrado es ",cuadrado;  
      Fin Proceso
```

que pondría como lógica?

Comment: Si prestas atención, para el cuadrado de 2 necesitas sumar 2 impares, para el de 3, 3, para el de 4, 4 y así sucesivamente.